# How to consume Microsoft Forms Authenticated WebServices in iPhone/iPad SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How to consume Microsoft Forms Authenticated WebServices in iPhone/iPad SDK? i.e.(Microsoft ASMX WebServices with SOAP response)

Advance Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) and supply the .wsdl file to auto-generate the classes to consume the Web Service.

Comment: does it support for Microsoft Forms Authenticated WebServices?

Comment: @KuldeepShige It will support any SOAP Web Service.